# HTML 5 video player update currentTime with given number

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

i want to update the `currentTime` with given number by user

For example i have video with 18.20 Mins of video, when user gives 1.46 as input it should play the video from 1.46 Mins, if user gives 4.56Mins it should play from 4.56Mins

What am trying is converting the given Minutes into number, but i think it is wrong

```
function minsToNumber(d) {
        d = Number(d);
        var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
        var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
        return ((h > 0 ? h + "." + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + "." + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
    }
```

any one can give correct calculation to do this ?

Comment: `var split=d.split('.'); var time=Number(split[0])*60+Number(split[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The HTMLMediaElement.currentTime property gives the current playback
>   time in seconds. Setting this value seeks the media to the new time.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)

So if you need 4 minutes 55 seconds, you have to use this value: 4*60 + 55 = 295

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.currentTime = 295; // seconds
```

**Complete sample:** (created in partnership with @Kaiido)

```
var toSeconds = function(time) {

  time = ('' + time).split('.');

  return +time[0] * 60 + +time[1];
};

toSeconds('4.55'); // 295
toSeconds(4.55); // 295
```

Comment: it says split is not a function

Comment: How did you call my function? `toSeconds('4.55')` or `toSeconds(4.55)` ? You have to pass a string parameter, not a number.

Comment: Yup sorry it was `toSeconds(4.55)` . Now its working :)

Comment: I have updated my sample. Now It works with numbers too. Try to call my function with number parameters. Example: toSeconds(4.55);

Comment: You would win one call to `split` by calling it in the string conversion : `var toSeconds = function(time) {
  time = ('' + time).split('.');
  return +time[0] * 60 + +time[1];
};`

Comment: Thanks guys you saved my day :)